# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' ...reason (key: networkCarrier)

Tags: ios, exception, arguments

I am getting this error in app, when i am running my iPad simulator

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: networkCarrier)'
```

please help me out with this issue ....its going to main thread

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Comment: What you trying to Achieve ? Can you post Some sample code ?

Answer (score 20):

Add exception breakpoint. This will cause the code to stop at the point where the error occurs. Goto xcode->View->Navigators->Show Breakpoint Navigator. In the left pane click on "+" and select "Add exception breakpoint". Run the application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add an object (which is nil) to dictionary for key"networkCarrier".